# when I return an array, I get a "cannot find symbol" error

Tags: java, arrays, return, output

I am creating a program where the user (teacher) enters a bunch of percentage grades, and these grades get analyzed, and an outputBox prints out the average, min/max, range, and the number of grades that are 'Level R', 'Level 1', 'Level 2' and so on.

The problem I am facing is the method which sorts the grades into different levels.
When I try to return my array to the main method, and try to print it to my output, I get an error for the array, saying "cannot find symbol"

```
import java.util.Arrays.*;



public Integer[] Levels(){
Integer[] levelCount = {0,0,0,0,0};
int mark = Integer.parseInt(markInput.getText());

int i;
for (i=0; i<levelCount.length;i++ )
{
    if (mark <50){
        levelCount[0] = levelCount[0]+1;
    }
    else if ((mark >= 50) && (mark <60)){
        levelCount[1] = levelCount[1]+1;
    }
    else if ((mark >=60) && (mark<70)){
        levelCount[2] = levelCount[2]+1;
    }
    else if ((mark >=70)&&(mark<80)){
        levelCount[3] = levelCount[3]+1;
    }
    else if ((mark >=80) && (mark<=100)){
        levelCount[4] = levelCount[4]+1;

    }
}

return levelCount;
```

so, when I go to my main method to print out all the information, I am supposed to put the `levelCount` array into ANOTHER array, which I did. Here is what I have:

```
String [] level = {"\nNumber at Level R: " + Levels(levelCount[0]), 
"\nNumber at Level 1: " +Levels(levelCount[1]), 
"\nNumber at Level 2: " + Levels(levelCount[2]), 
"\nNumber at Level 3: " + Levels(levelCount[3]),
"\nNumber at Level 4: " + Levels(levelCount[4])};
```

So my grand dilemma, is that the array `levelCount` shows the error `'cannot find symbol'`.
No matter what I try, I continue getting this error.

I feel like the answer is extremely obvious, but I searched online for something that would help me with this problem, and nothing seems to work, I keep getting the same error.

Comment: What IDE are you using?  PLease show stack trace

Comment: You do know that the `+` symbol , when you are talking about Strings, is concatenation and not addition, right ?  so "0" + 1 wont produce what you think it will.

Comment: You (evidently) have no method `Levels()` which takes a `String`, which is what you're looking for when you call `Levels(levelCount[0])`.

Comment: Unless you are purposely constructing strings that look like `"0111...11"`, `levelCount[0]+1` code is **not** going to do what you think it is going to do.

Comment: check this line `levelCount[5] = levelCount[5]+1;` in `Levels()`

Comment: Please describe the problem that you are trying to solve, rather than describing your solution. Unfortunately, there is no easy way to decipher what you were trying to do from the code that you have provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method Levels does not take any argument, so when you try to create the String array in the main method, that won't compile. Your Levels method returns String[] as well. Try changing the use of the method like this:

```
int[] levelCount = Levels();    
String [] level = {"\nNumber at Level R: " + levelCount[0], 
"\nNumber at Level 1: " + levelCount[1], 
"\nNumber at Level 2: " + levelCount[2], 
"\nNumber at Level 3: " + levelCount[3],
"\nNumber at Level 4: " + levelCount[4]};
```

And change the array to int or Integer as proposed by Asfab.

Comment: That fixes the problem, except now my output shows that either the 'R' level or '4' level has 5 marks, and all the other levels show 0, even if that is not true.

Comment: The input to the Levels seems to be a single mark, whereas the counting is done by looping through your levelCount array, which is always 5.

Answer (score 2):

Change line `Integer[] levelCount = {0,0,0,0,0};` to

`Integer[] levelCount = {0,0,0,0,0,0};`

Or remove `levelCount[5] = levelCount[5]+1;`

In the above line you are trying to read `6th` (index 5) element , but your declared Array size is 5 (i.e max index 4)